# attaching readonly to input using jquery

Tags: jquery

in my html I have the following rows

```
<li class="tagit-new">
 <input class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
 <span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span>
</li>
```

I want, using jquery to add attach the input field - readonly
I have this structure a few times in my html. can I add it to the first only?
What is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.tagit-new:first-of-type').find('input').prop('readonly', true);
```

this affects only the first input.

Comment: `.attr('readonly', 'readonly')` or `.prop('readOnly', true)`.  Pick one :)

Comment: This will work just because `'readonly'` is a string which is a truthy value, apart from that, value should be `true` or `false`. FYI: `readonly` is a  boolean property.

Comment: Only `attr('readonly', 'readonly')` works as expected (`readonly="readonly"`), `prop('readonly', 'readonly')` and `prop('readonly', true)` do both just the same: `readonly=""`

Comment: @Recode That's because it's boolean attribute/property.

Comment: @Recode: There's no DOM property named "readonly".  The property name has a capital 'O' in it, and is case sensitive.

Comment: @cHao what do you mean? `<input readonly="readonly">` is what jquery does.

Comment: @Recode: I thought i read somewhere about how they had fixed that.  :P   Either way, whether it works or not, it's incorrect -- and it'd only still work because jQuery (and to some extent, IE) did things wrong for so long that people expect it.  `readOnly` is the name of the DOM property, though, and is what you should use with `.prop`.  If/when jQuery ever actually *does* get around to unmuddling attributes and properties, `.prop('readonly', anything)` will magically break...whereas `.prop('readOnly', true_or_false)` will continue to work for as long as browsers support the W3C DOM.

Comment: on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_readonly.asp) it's also written lowercase, so please give me an article that shows that it should be readOnly ;)

Comment: @Recode: w3schools is well known for its often outdated and just plain *wrong* information.  A link to it means even less than "that's what my teacher told me" etc.  :P  As for articles...i can do even better than that.  I can point you at [the DOM specification itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-88461592).  The *attribute* name, being HTML, is case-insensitive; it doesn't matter what case you use there, unless you're one of those XHTML weenies.  But the DOM property (you know, the thing that `.prop` is *made* to mess with) is clearly `readOnly`.

Comment: never trust a teacher ;)

Answer (score 2):

Setting `readonly` property to `true` for the first macthed input element in several `li.tagit-now`.

```
$(".tagit-new input:first").prop('readonly', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ErdLg/

Setting `readonly` property to `true` for the first macthed input element in each `li.tagit-now`.

```
$(".tagit-new").find('input:first').prop('readonly', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pZcDq/